# Java Animation Issue

Tags: java, animation, timer

So I can get the rectangle to render to the screen but when I run the timer it just paints a growing rectangle across the screen rather than moving it as the rectangle it started as. Any help would be great, thank you.

Game Class

```
public class Game implements ActionListener{

static Game game;
Render render;

int x;
int y;
int velx = 2;


Game(){

    Timer timer = new Timer(10, this);

    render = new Render();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Game");
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(render);

    timer.start();         
}

public void render(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50); 
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    game = new Game();

}

@Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   int velx = 2;
   x = x + velx;
   render.repaint();

}  
}
```

Render Class

```
public class Render extends JPanel {
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

   super.paintComponents(g);

   Game.game.render((Graphics)g);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was when I did this.

```
super.paintComponents(g);
```

I changed it to this and it worked.

```
 super.paintComponent(g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initialising your timer like below (import javax.swing.Timer):

```
timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
        }

    });
```

Read up on it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)